# GPU within a for loop

Tags: python, keras, gpu

I am trying to do a for loop on a function that involves Neural Network. The `nn_f` is a function that train the Neural Network with Keras's backend set as GPU:

```
import os 
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend" # was #Tensorflow
os.environ["PLAIDML_EXPERIMENTAL"] = "1"  # i.e. y/n question in terminal : "1" represent yes 
os.environ["PLAIDML_DEVICE_IDS"] = "opencl_amd_gfx1010.0"
```

Running an individual `nn_f` is fast enough.

However, I find the loop is going extremely slower than expected and I wonder how to accelerate the whole process.

```
func = partial(nn_f,batch_size, epochs ...)
R_2_l = [ ]
for x, y in zip(param_l[0], param_l[1]):

           R_2_l.append(func(x,y))
```